# Fullcalendar not loading correctly in vue component

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

[image]

I am making a vue application, and I added a FullCalendar for a functionality. However, for a reason that I do not know, the calendar is put in the upper-left corner, and the days are not displayed. Funny thing is that if I open the browser console, the calendar displays as it should be.

This is what I have in the component:

```
<div>
<FullCalendar ref="calendar" :options="calendarOptions" />
```

```
import "@fullcalendar/core/vdom";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue3";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

export default {
  name: "CalendarE",
  components: { FullCalendar },
  data() {
    return {
     calendarOptions: {
       plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
       initialView: "dayGridMonth",
       selectable: true,
       height: 650,
       width: 700,
    },
  };
 },
 methods: {},
 };
```

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Probably a CSS issue. Did you inspected it with your devtools?

Comment: Yes, but I do not know what it could be, because the size is defined in the options.